# SQL: how to select rows where id is in comma separated string?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, string, select

I think i did a big mistake and i can't figure how to do this thing:

I have a table with a list of rooms and the column members (varchar) containing the list of accepted memberd id separated by commas (Es. 1,2,15,1000)

I need to select all rooms where id IN members string. Any idea??? Something like

```
SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE id IN rooms.members
```

(I know it wont work, but i hope i explained myself ^^' )

**EDIT**
*I need to do a sql query with PDO in PHP, I'm using MySQL and the goal is to get a list of all the rows where the id is listed in the members list string*

Comment: Please mention your dbms with version.

Comment: i have to do an sql query with php, why do you need my dbms? anyway is MySQL

Comment: Is it MySQL 8 or any older version?

Comment: @Chris DBMS is important because SQL is vendor-specific (and sometimes version-specific too). Any answer will need to consider your database. The client (php here) is what often is irrelevant for the DB engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL you can use `Find_in_set()` to get your job done:

DB-Fiddle:

```
 create table test (id int, studentIDs  varchar(50));
 insert into test values(1,'1,2,3');
 create table student (id int, name  varchar(50));
 insert into student values(1,'A');
 insert into student values(2,'B');
```

Query:

```
 select * from student where find_in_set(id,(select studentids from test))
```

Output:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c78040b55a60dc3068983d9a07b88f3a)*

If you are using sql server 2016 or above then can use string_split()

DB-Fiddle:

```
 create table test (id int, studentIDs  varchar(50));
 insert into test values(1,'1,2,3');
 create table student (id int, name  varchar(50));
 insert into student values(1,'A');
 insert into student values(2,'B');
```

Query:

```
 select * from student where id in (select trim(value) from test cross apply string_split(studentids,','))
```

Output:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=01d79ca57682107269a9709053cbe8d2)*

Comment: i'm using MySQL :/

Comment: @Chris I have added answer for MySQL.

Comment: I just found the solution myself thanks to your tips and it was the same! Thumbs up for you!

Comment: That's just great. Upvote for your effort. Best wishes.